# MP4 video doesn't start from frame 0 in some players. Why?

Tags: video, html5-video, mp4, video-processing

I'm noticing a weird issue with mp4 videos in my app. For some reason, some players do not start the video from frame 0, but rather drops the first few frames.

For example: http://www.gifgrabber.com/app/misc/uploads/c44116b.mp4 open this video in Chrome - you will see the video starts at "55". Open it in QuickTime or VLC, it starts at "54".

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have seen this as the video file above appears to be the same as in the question referred to below, but if not, this answer provides an explanation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29930249/334402